an airconsole usb connects then immediately disconnects in web terminal using NXP usb virtual comport
when trying to connect through the web terminal with an NXP usb device virtual com port i get a connect then an immediate disconnect.
i tried the device and then verified the set up with a FTDI serial port adapter which works.

I think you are looking for a different airconsole, probably the https://www.get-console.com/shop/en/29-airconsole-xl-20, wifi/bluetooth to serial / network adapter.
The airconsole here on StackOverflow is related to https://airconsole.com and more specifically game developers using our Game APIs from https://developers.airconsole.com.
